# Setting up localization in Kohana 3.0 framework with set_locale

Tags: localization, kohana

In a tutorial on setting up internationalization and localization, ["Kohana 2.4 I18N (internationalization and localization) Library"](http://pinoytech.org/blog/post/Kohana-2.4-I18N-internationalization-and-localization-Library) the author says:

> I'd put it in a Base Controller so that all Controllers inherit it.

This is the code:

```
I18n::set_locale('tl_PH');
```

I tried placing it in all the controller and places I could but is not working.

Where is the exact place in Kohana 3.0.4.2 that I should place it?

Comment: You should make a note of what Kohana version you are using!

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in `bootstrap.php`:

```
I18n::lang('tl-PH');
```

The `I18n::set_locale` function doesn't exist in Kohana 3. See [I18n class docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/I18n).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who wrote that article, but locale should be set using the config `locale.php` config file. You may have to copy it from `system/config/locale.php` into your `application/config/locale.php` and set the proper values.

Calling `I18n::set_locale()` should only happen if you need to *change* from the default (set in `locale.php`) to something different (like Dutch, English, etc...).

P.S I'm a Kohana 2.4 core dev...

Comment: sorry but there's isn't any locale.php file (Kohana 3.0.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the PHP locale, you will change this is in `application/bootstrap.php`, there is a `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.utf-8')` line there already which you can change to the correct language.

To set Kohana's internal language for translation, add a call to `I18n::lang('en-us')` (replace "en-us" with your language) after the `Kohana::init()` call, before `Route::set()`.